# Chrome DevTools protocol: how to configure a RequestPattern to capture all requests except those sent from the service server

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol

I need to handle all request except those sent from the service server.
At present, I do it using such a way: capture all requests and into handler filter service requests.

```js
 await client.Fetch.enable({
     patterns: [
        { requestStage: 'Request' }, 
        { requestStage: 'Response' }
     ], // handle all requests and responses.
 });

client.Fetch.on('requestPaused', async (event: RequestPausedEvent) => {
    if (isServiceRoute(event.request.url))
        await continueRequestOrResponse(client, event);

    ...
    //  Handle the necessary events
});
```

Question: Can I do this at `client.Fetch.enable()` stage? E.g setup the the `patterns` filter so, it passes all requests (`*`) and rejects the service routes (started from `https://service-domain-1.company.com` and `https://service-domain-2.company.com`).

Comment: is Network.setBlockedURLs usable for your case?

Comment: No, the `Network.setBlockedURLs` just block the specified urls. I need another thing: catch all routes instead of service (service routes should be loaded in regular way)